# Can I set a checkboxes name with a string?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I'm using `settLoadBooleans` as changing the checkboxes state based on a text file that got loaded. The problem is I need to set the name of the checkbox using the string I got from that text file.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form

    public static string curDir = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    public static string settingsdnt = curDir + @"\settings.dnt";
    public static int settNo = 1;
    public static string[] readSettdnt = File.ReadAllLines(settingsdnt);

    public void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Settings.VibeCheck();

            string getLineForBool = readSettdnt[settNo - 1].Substring(readSettdnt[settNo - 1].IndexOf(":") + 1);
            string getLineName = readSettdnt[settNo - 1].Substring(readSettdnt[settNo - 1].LastIndexOf(':') + 1);

            for (; settNo < 128; settNo++)
            {
                if (getLineForBool == "True" || getLineForBool == "False")
                {
                    settLoadBooleans(getLineName);
                }
            }
        }

    public static void settLoadBooleans(string settName)
        {
            string getLine = readSettdnt[settNo - 1].Substring(readSettdnt[settNo - 1].IndexOf(":") + 1);
            //thats where i need to change the string to checkbox
            if (getLine == "True")
            {
                settNameCb.Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                settNameCb.Checked = false;
            }
        }

in "class Settings"

    public static string curDir = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    
    public static void VibeCheck()
    {
        FileStream fs = File.Create(curDir + @"\settings.dnt");
        fs.Close();
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(curDir + @"\settings.dnt"))
            {
            for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("");
                }
            sw.Close();
            }
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is: When `settNo` hits a line that has "True" or "False" string after ":" it should change the checkboxes name to the string that created from that line we hit before and take the part before ":"

Comment: I'm not sure yet what you are trying to achieve, but this condition `getLineForBool == "True" && getLineForBool == "False"` is never true

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about that one

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong - you have a file with names of checkboxes in the format of `name:boolean` and you want to set your UI to the state saved in the file? So the question is how to find checkbox by name? Also it's not clear if you already have 128 checkboxes or you need to add them to form

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy that is entirely correct! The 128 part is a placeholder, most of those lines in the text file is empty for now, it will only look the lines that has ```:True``` or ```:False``` at the end and change those lines with this (the ```if (getLineForBool == "True" || getLineForBool == "False")``` line does that job), for other settings i will make another code (for example there might be 3 or more options with buttons you can choose for different things)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change from

```
if (getLineForBool == "True" && getLineForBool == "False")
```

to

```
if (getLineForBool == "True" || getLineForBool == "False")
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should change from

```
if (getLineForBool == "True" && getLineForBool == "False")
```

to

```
if (getLineForBool == "True" || getLineForBool == "False")
```

Then change like below

```
public static void settLoadBooleans(string settName)
{
     string getLine = readSettdnt[settNo - 1].Substring(readSettdnt[settNo - 1].IndexOf(":") + 1);

     //thats where i need to change the string to checkbox
     settNameCb.Text = settName;

     if (getLine == "True")
     {   
         settNameCb.Checked = true;
     }
     else
     {
        settNameCb.Checked = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to change the ```settNameCB.Text``` though, im trying change a checkboxes state. and for doing that i need to get the checkboxes name from the text file, which i did, then i need to convert that string to a checkbox variable. the string is "chkBxSettPShwMp" and i do have a checkbox that is called "chkBxSettPShwMp" but i need to use the string in settname to a checkbox so i can control "chkBxSettPShwMp" with that ```if``` part